# Flurry-ParamDistribution comparison

Tags: analytics, yahoo, flurry

I am sending event(event_payment_result) with more than one params and I am reviewing the parameters sent from Events > Parameter Distribution section. In this screen I can show only one parameter of event.

[image]

But I want to compare different params for this event. Are there any features for this comparison process? For example payment_type = Mastercard and is_succeed = TRUE

Answer (score 0):

On the Parameter Trend dashboard, you can compare parameter values from different parameters over time. Use the context boxes at the top to choose the Event param names, in your example "payment_type" and "is_succeed", then the boxes just above the graph to select the values, "Mastercard" and "TRUE". You will then see the two values compared over time.

Comment: Actually what I need is not to see all the parameters. To see if the value in the same event(event_payment_result) is mastercard while the other value is true or false. I want to calculate what percentage of the payment types are TRUE and what percentage are FALSE.

Comment: You could build this in Explorer. Set the metric to "Event Parameter - Occurrences", with the Event "event_payment_result", and the Parameter "payment_type", with the added constraint of "payment_type" = "Mastercard". Set the x-axis to session date/time. Add a Breakout on "Event Parameter", with the event "event_payment_result", and the parameter "is_succeed". List values for the parameter "is_succeed" and choose both true and false. You should see a graph of the number of times "payment type"=Mastercard, split between when it was logged and "is_succeed" is true, and when it is false.